# How to start a ux project (website) from scratch?

Tags: website-design, users, experience

I have been following the JJG elements of user experience design for most of my projects.[image]

Most of the time I don't have to start a website from scratch. They usually have the idea and I would be building the more "concrete" stuff like wireframes and flow charts.

However, I need to create the more "abstract" stuff(see img) for the website. This is the part where I am having the most trouble. How am I suppose to do this part?

I understand I should be asking all these questions and understand the product. I do have all these question down but its more of a one word answer for most of them. Are there any examples or projects or comments on how I should approach this?

Comment: It might be prudent to break this down to more concrete question(s).

Answer (score 1):

I usually start a website, getting information about the user, company and all stakeholders needs. I fill a 10+ page document asking several questions about all the relevant questions.

Questions like

- Who is the user?
- What is the most important thing user must do in the site

And so on. Asking this questions (you don't necessarily have to do answer), will give you the most relevant information you need to start your site.

Comment: I have a list of questions but they dont seem to help guide me to the right direction. Are there any samples or portfolio u can provide that I can check out?

Answer (score 0):

If Client do not able to provide Answers for your Questions, then try to collect some example websites which is already available, show that to the client ask questions on that. If he chooses one from your collected website, study on that website and create something like selected one with some UX amendment you see in selected website.

I usually do in this way, hope it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start from to bottom to the top of this framework. I'll give you a more practical guide.

1. **Start by gathering user requirements**: find your target audience users and **interview** them about how they use sites in your niche. Here you can do **surveys** too, or a combination of survey + interviews (best way). The point is to find as much information and user requirements, so you know what features you should design for your website. Then identify goals - how you are going to monetize the site.
2. **Develop prototypes or sketches** of the future site. Start from paper prototypes and make many variants with different layouts, information architecture, and try to validate them with users. Try to iterate and improve on your sketches. You should do at least 3-4 iterations. Then if you have time you can do high fidelity prototypes to further improve your concept. The more you test the more usable the site will be.
3. Try **card sorting** to get an idea how to structure your navigation menu. With card sorting you will get how users are thinking it would be better to structure the menu. Also, you can do **[first click test](http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/first-click-testing.html)** or **[5 seconds test](http://fivesecondtest.com/)** on your homepage as it is *very important*.
4. At this step your site should be already developed with main functionality working and you have to start refining it. You should constantly getting qualitative and quantitative information about it (e.g. Install [analytics software](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [make user tests](https://www.usertesting.com/)). Remember to identify your goal and start tracking conversions. After that you have  **start A/B testing** the headings of your pages, pictures, copy and other elements you think are important.
5. **Iterate!** Do user test and then A/B tests to improve your conversion rate. You should not stop doing this because it is will get you good return of investment.

Of course in the real world you might not have the time and resources to do it exactly like that, but thats generally a **optimal way of creating a very high quality website/app**. Wish you luck, you have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score 0):

UX treasure map,I would like to share a cheat sheet that I use for the UX process but my decision to use each step involves the understanding of user needs and business requirements. You can refer to the same : 
[image: enter link description here]